# What is the inverse of the function $f: x \mapsto (x,x^{2}) : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}^{2}$?

Tags: functions, inverse

Let $f: x \mapsto (x,x^{2}) : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}^{2}$ and let $Y := f(\mathbb{R})$. Then $\mathbb{R}$ and $Y$ are in injection via $f$. Moreover, since $Y$ is the range of $f$, certainly $\mathbb{R}$ and $Y$ are in surjection via $f$. Therefore, the sets $\mathbb{R}$ and $Y$ are in bijection via $f$.

I am not sure how to write out the inverse of $f$ in the form $f^{-1}: (y_{1},y_{2}) \mapsto x: Y \to \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: You're looking for the inverse of an immersive path.  May I ask: “Cui bono?”

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What about $(y_1,y_2)\mapsto y_1$?

Comment: Oh I thought about it, but not sure. Alright, thank you.

Comment: @GudsonChou Now you are sure?

Comment: By "law of large numbers". Based on the number of upvotes, I would maintain that it is the desired choice til I found it wrong. :)

Comment: @GudsonChou Yeah, that's how you prove theorems in modern mathematics: By simply stating them on math.stackexchange and counting the number of upvotes.

Comment: I am not sure what you are trying to say?

Comment: Your proposed approach seems speculative. I do not think people constantly doing that can go deep into any field...

Comment: @GudsonChou I'm trying to say that the number of upvotes doesn't prove anything. But in this case the proof is quite simple. If you don't see it I could add it to my answer. Just let me know.

Comment: Of course the function in your answer circ the function given is an indentity function. If this is your "proof", please save it.

Comment: Of course upvotes do not count in the absolute sense. But if you are statistically literate, then you know what I am trying to say.